# Conditional Formatting w.r.t. a non-contiguous range

Tags: google-sheets, filter, max, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

How can I make conditional formatting (in google sheets) based on non-contiguous cells in the same columns?

Example:

I want to highlight (with **Bold**) the maximum between [H4, H14, H24, H34 etc..] (i.e., all cells in H starting from H4, moving ten in ten).

How can I make this kind of conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=H4=MAX(FILTER(H$4:H, MOD(ROW(H$4:H)-4, 10)=0))
```

[image: 0]